# Update all rows in a MySQL table using single query

Tags: php, mysql

I am wondering from 2 days but didn't get any suitable solution for my problem. I am working on a project and here I stuck on updating all rows of a MySQL `table` using single Update Query in PHP. Let's Suppose I have the table like given below

```
id |  heading  |  description
---------------------------
1    heading1    desc1

2    heading2    desc2

3    heading3    desc3
```

Now I want to update the `heading, description` fields using single update query. how will I loop the form for this ? can somebody suggest the easy and most efficient way to do this.

Comment: dude... have you tried anything or did your teacher just assign some homework and you want someone else to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could be a simple updated

```
update my_table  
set heading  = 'my_value1',
    description = 'my_value2';
```

eventually you can add  some where for proper filter

```
update my_table  
set heading  = 'my_value1',
    description = 'my_value2'
where heading = 'a_value';
```

Comment: What's the problem for 100 rows .. ?   ... 100.000 ... 1000.000 .. and update is an update .. (if you need  you can limit,, but if you don't nedd...no)